# I am getting Empty Json Object in response listner as compared to postman. How can i get JsonArray from JsonObject in response?

Tags: java, android, json, api

In java `JsonObjectRequest` response listner code, I am getting wrong response i-e I'm getting response but it is different from that I am getting from postman.

I have tried simple json object request call using volley and in response listner I logged `response.toString()`.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObject = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            jObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Vultus Get Resposne Version2: " + response.toString());
                }

            }
```

Actual output :

> {"output":[]}

Expected output:

> {
>       "output": [
>           "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/spatial-production/5cb45c3787bfbc0f6e0d0d9d/sentinel-s2-l1c/png/2019-04-01T06:07:17.318Z_ndvi.png",
>           "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/spatial-production/5cb45c3787bfbc0f6e0d0d9d/sentinel-s2-l1c/png/2019-04-01_ndvi.png",
>           "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/spatial-production/5cb45c3787bfbc0f6e0d0d9d/sentinel-s2-l1c/png/2019-04-06T06:01:36.169Z_ndvi.png",
>           "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/spatial-production/5cb45c3787bfbc0f6e0d0d9d/sentinel-s2-l1c/png/2019-04-06_ndvi.png"
>       ]
>   }

Comment: Is there any configuration on the Postman request that could be missing? JSONObject is fairly straight-forward to manipulate if you follow the [Android documentation on it](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) specifically `getJSONArray(String name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array coming from your JSON object. You can try something like this..

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObject = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        url,
        jObject,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Vultus Get Resposne Version2: " + response.toString());

                try{
                    //String jsonStr = response.toString();
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray jsonData = jsonObj.getJSONArray("output");
                    int length = jsonData.length();

                    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        String url = jsonData.getString(i);
                        urls.add(url);
                    }
                } catch(JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Finally, use your ArrayList wherever you need it.

Something like this,

```
Url url1 = urls.get(0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works good but i have solved my issue using response.getJsonArray("output")

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please upvote it so that others who need help will get it as a search result.

Comment: @DeepakJ while this answer is mostly correct, you are creating an unnecessary String version of `response` and then creating a new `JSONObject` from that String - this is the exact same as the original `response` object. Just as an FYI to improve performance :) Also length should be based on `jsonData`, not `jsonObj`

Comment: @Mark I am very thankful for guiding me. Needing continuous suggestions from people like you. Thanks again.